# Extend Bootstrap Typeahead plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, autosuggest

I'm building a particular "autocomplete" using Bootstrap Typeahead and Ajax.

My code is similar to:

```
searchInput.typeahead({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/AllNamesAutoComplete',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { searchText: searchInput.val() },
            success: function (data) {
                var arr = [];
                $.each(data.AutoCompleteItemViewModel, function () {
                    arr.push(this.Name + " - <span>" + this.Position + "</span>");
                });
                return response(arr);
            }
        })
    },
    items: 6
});
```

In the push I pass two different values: `this.Name` and `this.Position`.

Everything works fine but if I type "`S`" as the first letter, it renders the `<span>` as well. I'd like to push my string as HTML but I still don't know how to do that.

One more thing is that I'd like, when the user clicks on the item in the autocomplete, to select only the `Name` and not `Name` and `Position`.

I would like to put HTML in the array for the source of Typeahead and then I'd like, on click, to render in the main input only a specific value and not both.

I took a look at "[Extend the bootstrap-typeahead in order to take an object instead of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182799/extend-the-bootstrap-typeahead-in-order-to-take-an-object-instead-of-a-string)" but I can not understand it because it's using Backbone.

Comment: If you don't mind using a custom fork, you can try [my version](https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead) which contains this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the **title** of the question for anyone stumbling in here. This is how you **extend** the Bootstrap plugin. (yes, I have read more then the title)

```
(function ($, app) {

    var Typeahead = $.fn.typeahead.Constructor;
    Typeahead.extend = app.extend;

    app.YourCustomTypeahead = Typeahead.extend({
        highlighter: function (items) {
            // proof that it's working
            console.log('custom highlighter');
            // to call the parent just do this
            return Typeahead.prototype.highlighter.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    });

}(window.jQuery, window.YourProjectNamespace));
```

Usage:

```
var typeahead = new app.YourCustomTypeahead($('selector'), { /* options */ });
```

---

In the example `app.extend` is a generic extention function such as that used by Backbone.

ie. (bellow requires underscore)

```
(function (app, $) {

    // Backbone's extend function
    app.extend = function(protoProps, staticProps) {

        var parent = this;
        var child;

        // The constructor function for the new subclass is either defined by you
        // (the "constructor" property in your `extend` definition), or defaulted
        // by us to simply call the parent's constructor.
        if (protoProps && _.has(protoProps, 'constructor')) {
          child = protoProps.constructor;
        } else {
          child = function(){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); };
        }

        // Add static properties to the constructor function, if supplied.
        _.extend(child, parent, staticProps);

        // Set the prototype chain to inherit from `parent`, without calling
        // `parent`'s constructor function.
        var Surrogate = function(){ this.constructor = child; };
        Surrogate.prototype = parent.prototype;
        child.prototype = new Surrogate;

        // Add prototype properties (instance properties) to the subclass,
        // if supplied.
        if (protoProps) _.extend(child.prototype, protoProps);

        // Set a convenience property in case the parent's prototype is needed
        // later.
        child.__super__ = parent.prototype;

        return child;
    };

}(window.YourProjectNamespace, window.jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a string into HTML with jQuery:

```
html = $('<div>hello</div>')[0]
```

Typeahead's source function only expects an array of strings. To change the output of these strings, look into adding a highlighter function. The highlighter function will accept an item argument and should return HTML:

```
searchInput.typeahead({
  source: function(request, response){
  ...
    arr.push({Name:this.Name, Position:this.Position});
  ...
  },
  highlighter: function(item){
    return "<div>"+item.Name+" - <span>"+item.Position+"<span></div>"
  },
  matcher: function(item){
    return item.Name.indexOf(this.query) > -1;
  },
  sorter: function(items){
    return items;
  },
  items:6
});
```

Edit: I made some changes so that source calls response with an array of objects instead of strings. Formatting of the output html should take place in your highlighter function. The matcher needs to be able to find the property inside the object to compare against your query. Sorter must also be overridden to prevent errors when typeahead attempts to sort strings inside source.

Comment: but how can I separate this.Name from this.Position?

Comment: I edited my example to work with an array of objects instead of strings

Comment: Your solution is perfect! But there is only one problem: on the `<li>` the `data-value=" ... "` return `[object Object]`... solved this it is perfect!

Comment: I'm trying different solution using 'select' and `updater` but nothing yet... do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should create your own "matcher" method. You could use the [original method](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js) as base for yours. The original method make use of "~" operator (I didn't know it) that you can read about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

```
searchInput.typeahead({
  ...
  matcher: function(item){
    // maybe some ugly solution to remove <span> markup
  },
  ...
});
```

Comment: I don't need to remove the `span`... I need to add the `span`... and the solution posted by **Cezary Wojtkowski** works nice but doesn't upload the `data-value` inside the `li`, so when I choose something from the list it render just `[object object]`