# Twitter Bootstrap, Typeahead, images

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to create Typeahead search with Twitter Bootstrap 2.2.1. I've managed to work with JSON and not strings like this:

```
$('#search').typeahead({
    minLength: 3,
    source: function (query, process) {
    $.post('@Url.Action(<MySearchAction>, <MyControllerName>)', { Text: query }, function (data) {
            var source = [];
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                source.push(JSON.stringify(value));
            });
            process(source);
        });
    },
    updater: function (item) {
        var itemJSON = JSON.parse(item);
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action(<MyDetailsAction>, <MyControllerName>)/' + itemJSON.ID;
    },
    highlighter: function (item) {
        var itemJSON = JSON.parse(item);
        return itemJSON.Name;
    },
});
```

Now I want to do more

1. Is it a right way to work with JSON in typeahead?
2. I want to show different types of objects in drop down - suppose I have Songs and Albums types, I want to show all Songs found then divider and then all Albums found.
3. I want to show images in dropdown - like covers of Albums.

I've read topic here [Allow loading images and custom HTML in typeahead results](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2441).
Quote from that topic: *"Using a combination of the item and menu options you can specify new templates"*, but I still do not get how to do it in a right way.

Thank you.

Comment: this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12307775/180100 might help.

Comment: @RC. thank you, I've seen that. What about an images?

Answer (score 1):

Since typeahead processes strings with the source function I used those strings as keys to access data.

Somewhat like this

```
$('#search').typeahead({
    myData: {"key":{image:"image.jpg",description:"lorem blahblah"}},
    source: //Load data in a function
        //add data to myData with the key being the string you would process, 
        //and the value being an object you want to get values from

    highlighter: function(item){
        var item = this.options.myData[item];
        var image = item.image;
        var description = item.description
        return "<img src='"+image+"'>" so on and so forth;
    }
```

That should get you started.